Problem with Facebook Link: Automatically Redirecting to an App on Android
I'm experiencing an issue with a Facebook link that I use on Android. This link is part of an extension I use to extract the access token directly from the browser. However, every time I click on the link, instead of staying in the browser, I'm automatically redirected to an app installed on my device.
I need the link to stay in the browser so I can complete the process as intended. Does anyone know how to prevent this automatic redirection to the app? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

In my case, when I open a link from a Facebook page in facebook app, it always redirects to the app. As a workaround to solve this issue, you can add an invalid package name in your Facebook Developer Console settings.
Steps:

Go to developers.facebook.com
Select your app
Find Android platform settings
Change the package name to something invalid (e.g., com.example.app -> com.example.app.invalid)

This will prevent Facebook from redirecting links while keeping Facebook Login working.
